# Enum object does not support indexing

Tags: python

I have an `Enum` object that has tuples as values. It is a direction `Enum`, so it has `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `UP` and `DOWN` that are tuples. The second value of the tuple is the direction delta.

If I want to retrieve this value it gives me the following error:

> 'Direction' object does not support indexing

I tried adding the `__getitem__` method but im not sure how I should properly implement this.

This is the `Enum` code:

```py
class Direction(Enum):
    DOWN = ("DOWN", (0, 1))
    UP = ("UP", (0, -1))
    LEFT = ("LEFT", (-1, 0))
    RIGHT = ("RIGHT", (1, 0))

    def __init__(self, id, movement_delta):
        self.id = id
        self.movement_delta = movement_delta

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

I want to use the direction delta this way:

```py
direction_num = random.randrange(4)

if direction_num == 0:
    direction = util.Direction.DOWN
elif direction_num == 1:
    direction = util.Direction.UP
elif direction_num == 2:
    direction = util.Direction.LEFT
else:
    direction = util.Direction.RIGHT

new_position = player_coords + direction[1]
```

This way I want to make it go a random direction and calculate the new position this way.

I expect the output to be the new position, but it gives the following error:

> TypeError: 'Direction' object does not support indexing

Comment: What is the type of `player_coords`? You need to provide a [mre] that reproduces the problem so other can test their solutions.

Comment: I suspect you are looking for a `dict` type variable. There, you can use the direction  name ('up', 'down', etc) as index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `type(direction)` will be `Direction`. Try `direction.value[1]`. That should work.

`type(direction.value) == tuple` and you can index the the required value.

```
>>> direction = Direction.DOWN
>>> type(direction)
<enum 'Direction'>
>>> print(direction, direction.name, direction.value)
DOWN DOWN ('DOWN', (0, 1))
>>> type(direction.value)
<class 'tuple'>
>>> direction.value[1]
(0, 1)
```